# Error parsing query from another page using current page data

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

I'm attempting to use data on another page (scholar progress reports) to match columns in a current page (copy of results).

Using the formula below:

`=QUERY('Copy of Results'!$A$2:$I$999, "select D where A="&'Scholar Progress Reports'!A158&"")`

Is producing the following error:

`"Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: test"`

where 'test' is the value of the cell I'm trying to match on the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 'test' is in cell A158 of the same sheet, the query is used, try:

```
=QUERY('Copy of Results'!$A$2:$I$999, "select D where A='"&A158&"'", 0)
```

Else, try

```
=QUERY('Copy of Results'!$A$2:$I$999, "select D where A='"&'Scholar Progress Reports'!A158&"'", 0)
```

Comment: That did it, thank you!  Although I ended up changing `'"&A158&"'` to `"""&A158&"""` to avoid apostrophe's causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought is exactly what the error says "NO_COLUMN: test". In your formula, are you trying to select a column, or something like that, called "test" instead of using the names "A", "B", etc.?

If that's not it, do you have a sample sheet?

[THIS](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/IAdv2S7Wo00;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Awindows) may also help.